# Extreme video stabilization in Linux, again

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editor, linux, stabilisation

I have a 3840x2160 MOV file taken with my EM1.II Olympus camera. It is a videoclip of a tiny bird taken in the wild without any aids. Hence, despite the good stabilization feature of the camera, the bird moves quite a bit along the frame. I want to stabilize the video USING LINUX ONLY (Fedora 35 fully updated).

I can crop A LOT, since the bird is quite small in the frame. Yet, the bird moves quite a bit in the frame, in a circle of around 800 pixels in diameter. But the video is not "blurred": the bird is fixed and sharp most of the time, thanks to the stabilization of the camera.

I tried to install Blender, but it does not run complaining about my old video card. I then tried Kdenlive without luck: the motion tracker effect was removed last year. So the natural clues I found in Google do not apply anymore.

Anyway, there should be a good way to stabilize the video using ffmpeg and other software. ffmpeg comes with a stabilization feature, but it only works for small movements, and my movements are not small at all.

Comment: You could try older versions of Blender. https://download.blender.org/release/

Answer (score 0):

DaVinci Resolve (free version) works on Linux and has good stabilization. I'm currently running Resolve 17 on Pop! OS 21.1 without a problem. To make a Debian type installer I used https://www.danieltufvesson.com/makeresolvedeb

Edit:
Somehow missed that you are on Fedora, however it does seem like some folks have it running on that distro.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I will try it. Here is a page for installing in Fedora: https://www.fosslinux.com/40081/how-to-install-davinci-resolve-on-fedora.htm

Comment: No luck. I installed it without problems, but when I run `/opt/resolve/bin/resolve` only a black window appears that I have to `CNTR-C`. Then it refuses to run again crashing.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit the comments on the link you posted suggest there are problems installing Resolve 17 on Fedora.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit You could try installing an older version like Resolve 16.1.1 Older versions are available here: https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/support/family/davinci-resolve-and-fusion

Comment: I tried 16.1.1. Exactly the same problem happens. It seems there's a problem with log4cxx: https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=61600